# two DIV side by side and aligned vertically at their bottom

Tags: css, html

I need two DIV to be put side by side and aligned vertically at their bottom.

- The orange div **doesn't have a width or height**. It can grow depending of his content
- I should be able to use padding and margin of the green div
- I would like to have a solution that doesn't use javascript

[image: a tall orange rect, a short green rect, base aligned]

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use a table and use valign.

Comment: The easiest way to do this and keep the fluid content in the orange div would be to put both of the divs inside a table and use valign bottom to keep both divs at the bottom no matter how big the orange div gets. This can be done with pure css but the table is the easiest way.

Comment: @AdamFordham, Easy != Best.  IMHO, using tables for layouts is sloppy coding.  SO is a self-moderated community and as long as the rules are followed, there is nothing wrong with posting critical comments.  In fact, my two comments below are simply factual statements.  One does not follow the OP's stated criteria and the other simply does not work at all.

Comment: @Sparky672, the first comment by AdamFordham have his place on SO. Doing the alignement of my 2 divs with table IS a possible solution. Maybe that its not the best one but for now its the only way that i've found to make it work. If there's a solution with DIV, i will give it a try for sure!

Comment: @AlexandreJobin, Perhaps you missed the pure CSS solution by thirtydot below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/J9eds/

I've used `display: inline-block` combined with `vertical-align: bottom`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
        left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />left<br />
        leftleftleftleftleftleft
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    float: left;
}
#left, #right {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background: #ccc;

    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
    /* ie6/7 */
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
}
#right {
    margin: 20px 20px 0 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I've been wanting to get better at using the `display` property, for purposes like these and such. Thx

Comment: i like your solution every time :)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but something like this should work:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="orange"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
</div>

div.wrapper div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

May not even need the float.

Comment: Use position absolute and remove the floating

Answer (score 1):

This was some fun practice :) Its probably not the best answer, but it should get the job done.

html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div id="div3">testing a whole<br/> bunch <Br/>of text and content t<br/>hat this co<br/>uld co<br/>ntain<br/> hadahdee<br/> wha da da deet</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="div4">nick</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
td
{
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

#div3
{
    border:solid 5px blue;
    float:left;
}
#div4
{
    width:50px;
    height:20px;
    border:solid 5px red;
    float:right;
}
```

see code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eGyh5/). add margins to the divs if you'd like

Comment: Not my downvote, but you probably got it for using a table for layout.

Comment: Well its an easy way to implement the v-align css. And why is mine the one getting downvoted when the others dont even work? lol

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using tables they are still supported and surprisingly they are making a huge comeback lots of sites using them.

Comment: Maybe someone's having a bad day. I have set you even.

Comment: @Adam, perhaps I was too harsh on you before for suggesting a table was the best solution in this case.  However, your last comment is not very believable... "tables making a huge comeback"?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you'll get something better but to get started this seems to work.
in the css sheet

```
#box1{
background-color:#FFFF99;
width: 350px;
height: auto;
float: left;
position:absolute;
bottom: 0; 
}

#box2{
background-color:#CCFF99;
width:350px;

left: 500px; 
position: absolute;
bottom: 0; 
}
```

in the html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<link rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" href="try2.css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="box1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 

nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 

esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 

in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 

nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 

esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 

in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 

nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 

esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 

in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>

<div id="box2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut 

labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 

nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 

esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt 

in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I think you need an absolute left position for the second box.

Comment: He clearly stated that the orange box does not have any width or height.

Comment: yes I saw that. wich is why i set the height to auto. But did not see a way around a no width unless there were some page breaks

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was applying this style to both divs:

> .bottom-align {
>   vertical-align:bottom; display:inline-block; float:none;
>   }

Then between both divs I had to remove the pseudospace by adding a blank comment:

```
</div><!-- ---><div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/panosang/96bnt3xa/

After some hours of working and a terrible headache i think that the perfect solution is to add some `margin-botton` and `margin-top` elements.

I really hate to add specific pixels or change percentage each time into my CSS file but i found it as the perfect solution in my problem.

I used `<table>` instead of `<div>`, but it works with `<div>` too.